# Fixed div at the bottom

Tags: html, footer, viewport, fixed

I'm learning HTML & CSS, and I'm having an issue.
My page is already built : a header, some blocks, a footer. Very simple, I'm a beginner.
I'd like the footer to stay fixed on the bottom until it reaches a limit situated 50px under the last block (if we scale the viewport). Then it should just stay there like a normal block... But I can't figure out how to make it happen!

Could you help me, please?

By the way, I speak French : if something isn't clear enough, please tell me and I'll try to explain.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Adrien.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of what you already have? You might benefit from it, cause the answers you get will (1) come faster, (b) be more accurate and (3) you will be able to apply the solution to your actual coding environment much more easily.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to handle this with purely CSS.

Firstly Twitter Bootstrap has a nice means of doing this. [Link is here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Or you could use the CSS Sticky Footer [See here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

The key is to create a negative bottom margin in the main container, using the exact height you want your footer to be.

I hope this helps.